# Sum multiple variables listed in character vector, in dplyr::mutate

Tags: r, symbols, dplyr

How can I get something like this to work? I want `all = sum(onecycle, twocycle)`, without having to type it all out.

```
library('dplyr')
library('english')
ex <- data.frame(onecycle = 1:10, twocycle = sample(1:10), recycle = sample(1:10), gvar = rep(1:5, each = 2))

ex %>% 
  mutate(all = sum(paste0(english(1:2), 'cycle'))
```

Comment: Isn't this done with `mutate_at`  and specify `matches("cycle")`

Comment: @akrun `mutate_at(paste0(english(1:2), 'cycle'), sum)` will sum each individual column. I want to sum the two variables for each row.

Comment: In addition, my real data has more columns whose names contain `"cycle"`, which I don't want to sum. So, I just want to sum the variables specified by a character vector.

Comment: `ex %>% mutate(v = Reduce(\`+\`, ex %>% select(ends_with("cycle"))))` though you should be able to write `.` or `.data` in place of the second `ex` ... I cannot figure that out.

Comment: Thanks @Frank. That's the part I was trying to figure out (`.`). If you've done a filter in a previous "pipe" operation and are mutating after, that method doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `dplyr::rowwise` or the `base::rowSums()`:

```
ex %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(cycle_sum=sum(onecycle,twocycle))
```

OR

```
ex %>% 
  mutate(cycle_sum = rowSums(.[paste0(english(1:2), 'cycle')]))
```

Comment: @Renu Np. Note, it does not if you just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one  option with `reduce`

```
libary(tidyverse)
ex %>% 
  select(matches('cycle')) %>% 
  reduce(`+`) %>% 
  mutate(ex, all = .)
```

---

Or another option is to `nest` and then use `map/reduce` within `mutate`

```
ex %>% 
   nest(-gvar) %>%
   mutate(all = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                  reduce(`+`))) %>%
   unnest
```

Comment: Any way to avoid typing `ex` twice? `ex %>% mutate(v = data.frame(.) %>% select(paste0(english(1:2), "cycle")) %>% reduce(\`+\`))` does it, but I can't imagine `data.frame(.)` is idiomatic.

Comment: @Frank Could use `as_tibble` `ex %>% mutate(all = as_tibble(.) %>% select(matches("cycle")) %>% reduce(`+`))`

Comment: Yeah, that still feels hacky, though. My understanding of pipes leads me to expect `.` to be equivalent to the LHS of `LHS %>% RHS` ... hm, in fact it already is a data.frame: `ex %>% mutate(v = str(.))` so I'm even more confused.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
ex$all=ex %>% select(ends_with("cycle"))%>% rowSums()
```

Comment: That works. I'll accept if no one has a better answer. This doesn't really fit into a pipeline if you've e.g. done a filter in a previous pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some methods I found using `rlang::syms`

```
ex %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(all = sum(!!!syms(paste0(english(1:2), 'cycle'))))

ex %>% 
  mutate(all = list(!!!syms(paste0(english(1:2), 'cycle'))) %>% reduce (`+`))
```

Comment: ```
ex %>% 
  mutate(all = list(!!!syms(paste0(english(1:2), 'cycle'))) %>% reduce (`+`))
```
This was super fast and worked like a charm!  Thanks @IceCreamToucan

Answer (score 0):

```
library('purrr')

ex %>% 
  mutate(total = pmap_dbl(select(., onecycle, twocycle), sum))

   onecycle twocycle recycle gvar total
1         1        7       8    1     8
2         2        9       9    1    11
3         3        4       6    2     7
4         4        2       7    2     6
5         5        3      10    3     8
6         6        8       3    3    14
7         7        1       2    4     8
8         8       10       1    4    18
9         9        6       5    5    15
10       10        5       4    5    15
```